# Twitter-bootstrap custom icon position not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am new in Angular and i have used Bootstrap in the pages design, but the default glyphicon icons ... huuum ... well
I have readed this tutorial http://favbulous.com/post/1006/create-custom-icons-for-twitter-bootstrap-easily but not work for me. The icons it's showing but the position is not that i want, the icons shows top of the text not to the left. I have this code

```
<a href="" ng-click="logout()"><i class="rpe rpe-user"></i> Logout </a>
```

The icon is on the top of the text

With glyphicon works well

```
<a href="#!/informeCobro"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Mantenimientos </a>
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you setup a demo of your code?

Comment: Can you show us the html of the admin drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
 display: inline-block;
```

to your class for image

Comment: If the answer is right. please check as accepted.. thanks